# IPhone: Copy/Clone

Tags: iphone, copy, clone

I want to copy or clone a object of my own written class.
But if I call the copy function only the pointer were copied. So if I change the copied object the original object is changed, too.

Is there a way/function to really clone an object?

best regards
Melanie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object can be copied if its class adopts the NSCopying protocol and implements its single method, [copyWithZone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCopying/copyWithZone%3a).

See [Object copying](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html)

---

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    MyClass *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
    [copy setProperty1:[self property1]];
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I already read this. But I dont really understand what zone is? "The zone identifies an area of memory from which to allocate for the new instance. If zone is NULL, the new instance is allocated from the default zone, which is returned from the function NSDefaultMallocZone." So what do I have to write for Zone?

Comment: @MeMa, nice comment. I think you don't need to worry about NSZone, just use default zone. NSZone allow to store information for allocation, handling and freeing objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is refered to as Deep Copy, where you want to copy the contents of a pointer, not the address it points to.

There are a few stack overflow questions about this list Below:

- [Highly Recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c)
- [Recomended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647260/deep-copy-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)
- [Worth Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595170/why-am-i-having-trouble-with-a-deep-copy-in-objective-c)

Additionally here is a article from Techtopia: [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Copying_Objects_in_Objective-C)

Addition here is my Google Search: [Here](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=Core%20Plot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=3SQ&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&source=hp&q=Obj-C%20Deep%20Copy&oq=Obj-C%20Deep%20Copy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=390911l395197l1l395297l17l16l0l7l0l0l354l2535l2-6.3l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=bdeb326aa44b07c5&biw=1920&bih=956)

Comment: Thank you. I did't know that this is called deep copy :-)